# int skipping when it's supposed to ask input

Tags: c

anyone can help me correct  with what's wrong with my code? int behaves in a funny way as it skips instead of having me input a number. thanks all.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>


char* input_text(const char* question)
{
   char* v = (char*)malloc(256);
   printf("%s ", question);
   if(fgets(v, 255, stdin) == NULL){
      free(v);
      return(NULL);
    }

   int len = strlen(v);
   if (len > 0 && v[len-1] == '\n'){
       v[len-1] = 0;
    }
    return(v);
}

int input_number(const char* question)
{
   int k = 0;
   printf("%s", question);
   scanf("%d", &k);
   return(k);
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
 {
   char* name = input_text("What is your name?  ");
   int age = input_number("What is your age?   ");
   char* bday = input_text("When is your birthday?   ");
   char* bstfriend = input_text("What is the name of your bestfriend?   ");


   printf("\n");
   printf("Your name is %s \n", name);
   printf("Your age is %d \n", age);
   printf("Your birthday is %s \n", bday);
   printf("Your bestfriend is %s \n", bstfriend);
   return(0);
 }
```

Also rearranging it is a no no since it was specifically instructed to put it that way.

Comment: Your code won't even compile. Where is `k` declared?

Comment: @CoolGuy oops. my mistake. Edited it now.

Comment: Show the input. Are you sure it is being the `int` is being skipped and not the input for birthday?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem but 1) `char* v = (char*)malloc(256);` → `char* v = malloc(256);` 2)`fgets(v, 255, stdin)` → `fgets(v, 256, stdin)` 3) You print everything even if`input_text` returns `NULL`. Take proper action 4)`free` `name`, `bday` and `bstfriend` after those `printf`s

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I edited it now. I forgot to edit that part. sorry.

Comment: scanf("%d", &k) won't read in the newline so the scanf() for the birthday won't wait for your input and just read the lefeover newline. you should also use fgets to read in the age into a char string and use sscanf to get the age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input_number()` function is leaving a newline in the input stream after the age is entered. The easiest fix is to add a `getchar()` to consume the unwanted newline after the `scanf()` in `input_number()`:

```
int input_number(const char* question)
{
   int k = 0;
   printf("%s", question);
   scanf("%d", &k);
   getchar();
   return(k);
}
```

Alternatively, you could write a function to clear the input stream:

```
void clear_input(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        continue;
    }
}

...

int input_number(const char* question)
{
   int k = 0;
   printf("%s", question);
   scanf("%d", &k);
   clear_input();
   return(k);
}
```

The `scanf()` and `fgets()` functions don't always work well together, since `scanf()` leaves newlines behind in the input stream, so it is usually better to stick with `fgets()`. You can use `sscanf()` to parse the input, and then there is no need to clear the input stream (unless the user enters more input than the buffer will hold; then the extra characters need to be handled):

```
int input_number(const char* question)
{
   int k = 0;
   char buffer[100];
   printf("%s", question);
   fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin);
   sscanf(buffer, "%d", &k);

   return(k);
}
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much!